# Show Dynamic Dropdown list for Text Searchable editable WPF COMBOBOX

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, combobox

I have a Combobox which is below. It is working fine. **Only Problem** is that when i type in it open complete list. But i want that lets say that if i type 'A' then dropdown should only show those words starting with 'A'

```
<ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,43,140,0" Name="comboBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="169" IsEditable="True" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" PreviewTextInput="ComboBox_PreviewTextInput"/>


private void ComboBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
    comboBox.IsDropDownOpen = true;
}
```

And my dropdown binding is below.

```
public void BindMedicalStoreComboBox(ComboBox comboBox1)
{
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select medical_store_id,m_store_name FROM medical_store", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "medical_store");
    comboBox2.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    comboBox2.DisplayMemberPath = ds.Tables[0].Columns["m_store_name"].ToString();
    comboBox2.SelectedValuePath = ds.Tables[0].Columns["medical_store_id"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40855376/937093 According to that answer on a similiar question, setting `TextSearch.TextPath` to the same value as your `DisplayMemberPath` should work.